# Instagram's API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

After the deprication of the instagram's API which provides the information about the followers of a user, some 3rd party apps can still provide the information of user's connection. What is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 2):

I assume they are using a private Instagram API by reverse engineering it.

One way to do that is to observe the requests your browser makes (with the developer tools) and then remake the requests in their own code, providing the proper data, cookies, etc.

It can all be observed through the developer tools.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Beside IG's public API which is deprecated now, there are other solutions to achieve this. they may have bought the data from facebook inc or use tools and libraries like [instagram private api](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API).